# Merging similar dictionaries in a list together

Tags: python, dictionary

New to python here. I've been pulling my hair for hours and still can't figure this out.

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
[ {'FX0XST001.MID5': '195', 'Name': 'Firmicutes', 'Taxonomy ID': '1239', 'Type': 'phylum'}
  {'FX0XST001.MID13': '4929', 'Name': 'Firmicutes', 'Taxonomy ID': '1239','Type': 'phylum'},
  {'FX0XST001.MID6': '826', 'Name': 'Firmicutes', 'Taxonomy ID': '1239', 'Type': 'phylum'},
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .

  {'FX0XST001.MID6': '125', 'Name': 'Acidobacteria', 'Taxonomy ID': '57723', 'Type': 'phylum'}
  {'FX0XST001.MID25': '70', 'Name': 'Acidobacteria', 'Taxonomy ID': '57723', 'Type': 'phylum'}
  {'FX0XST001.MID40': '40', 'Name': 'Acidobacteria', 'Taxonomy ID': '57723', 'Type': 'phylum'} ]
```

I want to merge the dictionaries in the list based on their Type, Name, and Taxonomy ID

```
  [ {'FX0XST001.MID5': '195', 'FX0XST001.MID13': '4929', 'FX0XST001.MID6': '826', 'Name': 'Firmicutes', 'Taxonomy ID': '1239', 'Type': 'phylum'}
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .

    {'FX0XST001.MID6': '125', 'FX0XST001.MID25': '70', 'FX0XST001.MID40': '40', 'Name': 'Acidobacteria', 'Taxonomy ID': '57723', 'Type': 'phylum'}]
```

I have the data structure setup like this because I need to write the data to CSV using csv.DictWriter later.

Would anyone kindly point me to the right direction?

Comment: The labels (`FX...`) and what seems like an ID of those items are just another key:value pair in a dictionary of attributes of those items? That seems wrong to start with, how would you know which key is the label? Because it starts with `FX...`? Because it's the only one thats not Type, Name, or Taxonomy ID?

Comment: Your data is not two dimensional, and therefore not a good fit for a csv file.  (Each key corresponds with a column -- but in your data, each dictionary will have different keys.)

Comment: I can probably  improve my data structure.  Basically I need the values of 'Type', 'Name' and 'Taxonomy" to be my row labels. The value of 'FX...MID.." is the data. The 'FX..MID..." are my column labels

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the groupby function for this:

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

```
from itertools import groupby

keyfunc = lambda row : (row['Type'], row['Taxonomy ID'], row['Name'])

result = []

data = sorted(data, key=keyfunc)
for k, g in groupby(data, keyfunc):
    # you can either add the matching rows to the item so you end up with what you wanted
    item = {}        
    for row in g:
        item.update(row)
    result.append(item)

    # or you could just add the matched rows as subitems to a parent dictionary
    # which might come in handy if you need to work with just the parts that are
    # different
    item = {'Type': k[0], 'Taxonomy ID' : k[1], 'Name' : k[2], 'matches': [])
    for row in g:
        del row['Type']
        del row['Taxonomy ID']
        del row['Name']
        item['matches'].append(row)
    result.append(item)
```

Comment: Nice! I _knew_ it can be done by using `itertools.groupby`, but couldn't quite get it working until you posted your answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I really need to learn more about the stuff in itertools!

Comment: the fisrt 2 lines of the outer loop are not needed

Comment: Without those two lines you would have to do g = list(g) and then item = g[0] since g is an iterator.

Comment: @Nathan : they could be replaced by "item={}"

Answer (score 3):

Make some test data:

```
list_of_dicts = [
                 {"Taxonomy ID":1, "Name":"Bob", "Type":"M", "hair":"brown", "eyes":"green"},
                 {"Taxonomy ID":1, "Name":"Bob", "Type":"M", "height":"6'2''", "weight":200},
                 {"Taxonomy ID":2, "Name":"Alice", "Type":"F", "hair":"black", "eyes":"hazel"},
                 {"Taxonomy ID":2, "Name":"Alice", "Type":"F", "height":"5'7''", "weight":145}
                ]
```

I think this (below) is a neat trick using `reduce` that improves upon the other `groupby` solution.

```
import itertools
def key_func(elem):
    return (elem["Taxonomy ID"], elem["Name"], elem["Type"])

output_list_of_dicts = [reduce((lambda x,y: x.update(y) or x), list(val)) for key, val in itertools.groupby(list_of_dicts, key_func)]
```

Then print the output:

```
for elem in output_list_of_dicts:
    print elem
```

This prints:

```
{'eyes': 'green', 'Name': 'Bob', 'weight': 200, 'Taxonomy ID': 1, 'hair': 'brown', 'height': "6'2''", 'Type': 'M'}
{'eyes': 'hazel', 'Name': 'Alice', 'weight': 145, 'Taxonomy ID': 2, 'hair': 'black', 'height': "5'7''", 'Type': 'F'}
```

FYI, [Python Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) is **far** better for this sort of aggregation, especially when dealing with file I/O to .csv or .h5 files, than the `itertools` stuff.

Comment: Thank you! I will check out the Python Pandas

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to create a new dictionary, indexed by a (Type, Name, Taxonomy ID) tuple, and iterate over your dictionary, storing values by (Type, Name, Taxonomy ID).  Use a default dict to make this easier.  For example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
grouped = defaultdict(lambda : {})

# iterate over items and store:
for entry in list_of_dictionaries:
    grouped[(entry["Type"], entry["Name"], entry["Taxonomy ID"])].update(entry)

# now you have everything stored the way you want in values, and you don't
# need the dict anymore
grouped_entries = grouped.values()
```

This is a bit hackish, especially because you end up overwriting "Type", "Name", and "Phylum" every time you use `update`, but since your dict keys are variable, that might be the best you can do.  This will get you at least close to what you need.

Even better would be to do this on your initial import and skip intermediate steps (unless you actually need to transform the data beforehand).  Plus, if you could get at the only varying field, you could change the `update` to just: `grouped[(type, name, taxonomy_id)][key] = value` where key and value are something like: 'FX0XST001.MID5', '195'

Comment: So this would produce a dictionary with (Type, Name, Taxonomy ID) as key and the rest as values?

Comment: @WonderSteve, yes, the only advantage over groupby is that you can use this to skip an intermediate data structure while importing. If you use the `update` method, `Type`, `Name`, and `Taxonomy ID` will also be in the dicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [ {'FX0XST001.MID5': '195', 'Name': 'Firmicutes', 'Taxonomy ID': '1239', 'Type':'phylum'},
  {'FX0XST001.MID13': '4929', 'Name': 'Firmicutes', 'Taxonomy ID': '1239','Type': 'phylum'},
  {'FX0XST001.MID6': '826', 'Name': 'Firmicutes', 'Taxonomy ID': '1239', 'Type': 'phylum'},
  {'FX0XST001.MID6': '125', 'Name': 'Acidobacteria', 'Taxonomy ID': '57723', 'Type': 'phylum'},
  {'FX0XST001.MID25': '70', 'Name': 'Acidobacteria', 'Taxonomy ID': '57723', 'Type': 'phylum'},
  {'FX0XST001.MID40': '40', 'Name': 'Acidobacteria', 'Taxonomy ID': '57723', 'Type': 'phylum'} ,]

kk = ('Name', 'Taxonomy ID', 'Type')

def key(item): return tuple(item[k] for k in kk)

result = []
data = sorted(data, key=key)
for k, g in groupby(data, key):
    result.append(dict((i, j) for d in g for i,j in d.items()))


print result
```